# A conceptual question on turning power on/off for a wireless communication

Tags: modem

I want to interface a wireless modem with a micro-controller.

What I want to achieve is that when I send a signal to the wireless modem I want the power to be turned on and when the modem does not receive any signals I want the power to turn off.

How can this be possible?

Here below I want to turn on off Power_gmod.

[image]

Comment: Your question doesn't have nearly enough details to be answerable.

Comment: What kind of modem and uC do you use? How do you connect them?

Comment: I edited mt question made an illustration. I want the Power_gmod(modem's power) to turn of when not receiving any messages; and I want it to turn on when receives a message.

Comment: What type of GSM module do you want to use? The datasheet has information about power saving modes and how to operate them, but for that you need a certain module with a datasheet.

Comment: I dont want the built in power saving mode. I want the power supply of modem to completely turn off or on.

Comment: If the modem is off, how does it know when a message is received to turn on?

Comment: thats the reason im asking this question. can there be a way?

Comment: There is no way this can be done without some compromise in your requirements. A receiver needs power to be able to adequately receive a proper signal.

Comment: okay but can there be at least a way to minimize the power use. @Andy aka i want  to send just lets say 2 bytes of data per day(in an unknown time) and don't want the modem power to consume power when not receiving any data. any ideas how can i implement an extra circuitry to achieve this.

Comment: You could switch the modem on every say 5-10 minutes to check for new messages, then switch it off to save power. Still, a power saving mode can be a better solution.

Comment: power saving mode can be a better solution but builtin power saving mode may not be optimized for a particular application. i want to minimize this power.

Comment: How much response time do you need i.e. if you send a a 2 byte message, do you need the receiving modem to see this information straight away? Maybe the transmitter can regularly send the two byte data and when the receiver wakes up (for say) 1 minute every hour, it receives this data. Alternatively, the receiver could wake up for ten seconds every hour and request data to be sent to it?

Comment: @Andyaka commentators here all tell that it is not possible straight away. only way is to make microcontroller to check periodically. just need to send a few bytes of data per day.

Comment: @user16307 I have asked you what your response time is and suggested possible other ideas so what is the point you are trying to make in the above comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for SMS messages to be recieved, there absolutely, definitely has to be power going to the wireless modem. There is absolutely no way around this.

Best thing you can do is to switch the modem on for a short period, say 15 seconds, which should be enough to receive any messages - do this say once every 5 minutes, or once an hour, or whatever. All this can be controlled by the microprocessor, which would have to be running this whole time. (Although it can be in standby mode while doing the timing, which would use virtually no current at all).

There is no other way. This is why pagers and mobile phones have to be on to receive calls and texts!!! They can't just magically switch on when there's a message or call waiting for them. There has to be active circuitry which does the looking out for a message or a call. And the circuitry which does this, HAS to be the modem. However, rest assured, these GSM modules and so on are designed by very knowledgeable teams following highly optimized standards, and represent state-of-the-art, and are designed to consume as little power as is necessary for this very task you ask of it. So if you use it as it is supposed to be used, (i.e. make best use of its standby features) then you can be sure that you are using the best possible solution.

The fact that you only need to receive a few bytes is inconsequential. The act of receiving an SMS involves far, far more data. And the data isn't even the problem with respect to power: receiving a message involves a complex "Handshake" which involves the thing doing the receiving to actually send data as well. That aspect consumes a lot of power. (And that is on top of the amplifying circuitry that does the receiving). This is why the modem needs to be on to receive messages.

The reason for the handshake being necessary is down to authentication and encryption. The cell tower and network provider need to know that the device in question is the one meant to receive the SMS. So first, when you send an SMS to a device, the network has to first of all find what it thinks is the destination device. So your modem would have to send pings out so the towers know where it is. Then when the tower has an SMS to send, it has to "talk" to the device, in order to authenticate that it is genuinely the correct recipient before sending the data. And all this has to be done with encryption so that firstly, no-one else can intercept the data, and more importantly, so no-one can intercept the authentication credentials (which would allow them to steal your device's identity, and any further data that is sent to it, or fake data coming from it).

Comment: So basically what I understood is, it is not possible to receive data straight away if the modem is off and one needs to turn it on/off periodically by a microcontroller in a standbye mode. That was clear. But if I just need to receive a few bytes per day, is the only way sending it by SMS via GSM? Does data size has nothing to do with power?

Comment: Correct. 1 byte or 100 bytes, bvasically no difference in power usage. No sense in using anything but GSM to send SMS messages - AFAIK other newer protocols would add unnecessary complexity and cost, and I don't think they would be any more energy efficient, but I could be wrong on that.